# Create function in R with if, else if, else

Tags: r, if-statement, data.table

I try to create a summarizing column from multiple conditions. The dataframe looks like the following:

```
dt <- data.table(ID=c(1,2,3,4,5,6),Condition1=c(1,0,1,1,0,0),Condition2=c(0,0,0,1,0,0),Condition3=c(0,1,1,1,0,1), Condition4=c(0,1,1,1,0,0))
str(dt)
 $ ID        : num  1 2 3 4 5 6
 $ Condition1: num  1 0 1 1 0 0
 $ Condition2: num  0 0 0 1 0 0
 $ Condition3: num  0 1 1 1 0 1
 $ Condition4: num  0 1 1 1 0 0
```

The summarizing column should give the highest value if all 4 conditions = 1, and lower values if only three, two or one condition are present. The end result should look like the following:

```
 $ ID        : num  1 2 3 4 5 6
 $ Condition1: num  1 0 1 1 0 0
 $ Condition2: num  0 0 0 1 0 0
 $ Condition3: num  0 1 1 1 0 1
 $ Condition4: num  0 1 1 1 0 0
 $ Summary   : num  2 3 4 5 0 1
```

I tried to use `if` and `else if` and `else`.

```
dt$Summary <- if(c(dt$Condition1 == 1 & dt$Condition2 == 1 & dt$Condition3 == 1 & dt$Condition4 == 1)){
  print("5")
} else if (c(dt$Condition1 == 1 & dt$Condition32 == 1 & dt$Condition4 == 1)){
  print("4")
} else if (c(dt$Condition3 == 1 & dt$Condition4 == 1)){
  print("3")
} else if (dt$Condition1==1){
  print("2")
} else if (dt$Condition3==1){
  print("1")
} else {
  "0"
}
```

But this is giving me an error.

The original dataset is longer and complexer. If possible a solution in `data.table` is appreciated. I want to make sure that only one summary value is assigned for each ID.

Comment: In your expected output, the first row has one condition and a summary value of 2. But the last row has one condition and a summary value of 1. Can you explain how you get there? More generally it doesn't look like you're assigning each condition equal value. So what are the weights associated with each condition?

Comment: you have a typo in your code ``dt$Condition32``

Comment: You are writing an "anti-pattern" and should avoid this mess!   Consider simple filtering, e.g.  `y <- x[x > 3  & x < 5]`  and so on.  Any time you have more than one "else if"  you should either do direct filtering or consider using  `?switch`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The canonical and more-efficient way to do this in `data.table` is to use `fcase`.

```r
dt[, Summary := fcase(
  Condition1 == 1 & Condition2 == 1 & Condition3 == 1 & Condition4 == 1, "5", 
  Condition1 == 1 & Condition3 == 1 & Condition4 == 1, "4", 
  Condition3 == 1 & Condition4 == 1, "3",
  Condition1 == 1, "2", 
  Condition3 == 1, "1", 
  rep(TRUE, .N), "0")]
#       ID Condition1 Condition2 Condition3 Condition4 Summary
#    <num>      <num>      <num>      <num>      <num>  <char>
# 1:     1          1          0          0          0       2
# 2:     2          0          0          1          1       3
# 3:     3          1          0          1          1       4
# 4:     4          1          1          1          1       5
# 5:     5          0          0          0          0       0
# 6:     6          0          0          1          0       1
```